# How to get the Ubuntu version via PHP?

Tags: php

If I try `phpinfo()` I see that System is:

```
Linux php56-web-68 4.4.0-142-generic #168-Ubuntu
```

But I have no idea what Ubuntu version is it? Is it 14.04 or 16.04 or something else?

Is there a way I can get this information just using standard PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another alternative is to use `cat /etc/lsb-release` command and feed it into PHP's `shell_exec`.

`shell_exec` should yield similar to this:

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS"
```

After that, just use `parse_ini_string` to *parse* the output, in turn returns an array.

Here's a one liner:

```
echo parse_ini_string(shell_exec('cat /etc/lsb-release'))['DISTRIB_RELEASE'];
```

Sidenote: Just tested on my ec2 instance, it yields `18.04`

A better version than the previous answer above suggested by @jenesaisquoi:

```
echo shell_exec('lsb_release -sr'); // 18.04
```

Comment: Wow, you are my hero. Your solution worked. The output is 16.04. What a relief ;). It's interesting though, that the other direct shell_exec() suggestions by others in this thread didn't work and the output was nothing. But your parse_ini_string worked, so, thanks again.

Comment: @jenesaisquoi this! `echo shell_exec('lsb_release -sr');`

Comment: What is wrong with parse_ini_file('/etc/lsb-release') ? why would you use cat and shell exec in this case ?

Answer (score 1):

You can call shell commands with shell_exec();

```
$version = shell_exec('lsb_release -a');
echo $version;
```

> Distributor ID: Ubuntu
>
> Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
>
> Release:        18.04
>
> Codename:       bionic

From that you can parse the info you need.

Comment: Hmm, there is no output at all. Can be this command not allowed?

Comment: This should be allowed by the web servers / php process.

Answer (score 1):

It's aviable with this command

```php
$ubuntu_version = explode("\t",shell_exec('lsb_release -a | grep Release'))[1];
```

Comment: There is no output. Any other way how to get this information?

Answer (score -2):

If you want to check ubuntu version via terminal than you can check it with below command

```
lsb_release -a
```

Comment: I need that for PHP not for shell.